# Is the keyword END a noun or a verb?

Tags: language-design

Quite a few programming languages use the keyword END to mark the end of a structured statement or the end of a procedure declaration etc. Is this word to be read as a noun or as a verb (in imperative)? In some human languages other than English the noun form of this word is different from the verb form such as *SLUT* and *SLUTA* in Swedish.

Comment: In the context of a block scope, it would be a verb. It really depends on the usage. It can be used as both in English.

Comment: What is the material difference in interpretation, for language design, between the verb and the noun?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark There would be no difference in interpretation but if the programming language was to use keywords in say Swedish the designer would have to choose between *SLUT* and *SLUTA*, or use both in different contexts.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It's a lucky coincidence then (and a nice property of the English language) that the same keyword END can be used in both declarations and statements without sounding wrong.

Comment: So in Swedish and, I suppose, many other languages you'd want to match the noun which means 'end' with the noun that means 'beginning', or the verb which means 'end' with the verb which means 'begin'.  I'm still struggling to understand why you don't just choose one interpretation and get on with it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think Mr. Polywhirl has the answer to my question in the first comment -- END is either read as a noun (in declarations) or as a verb (in statements). My conclusion then was that if the keyword language hadn't been English, two different words may have been needed to make it "grammatically correct."

Answer (score 0):

Many other keywords are ambiguous and could be nouns or verbs.

Languages that use `end` often use it with other verbs like:

- begin ... end
- do ... end
- repeat ... end

So you could imagine that `end` is a verb. But in English, it doesn't make a real difference. Keywords are often chosen because they are short. You may introduce a value with a verb like `let` or not a verb (`var`, `const`).

Endings / declensions are often avoided for convenience and to keep the keywords short (code doesn't try to be grammatically correct).

Comment: We also have type or variable declarations containing `RECORD ... END` where it's more natural to read END as a noun.